# compile c++ source code from another c++ program

Tags: c++, compilation, build-automation

I am making a compiler from brainfuck into c++, and I have gotten everything made up to the point where I actually compile the .cpp file that the program creates. I would really prefer to have the compiler actually be able to spit out an executable instead of just source code for c++, so how could I do this on Windows? 
The .cpp is created in the same directory as the compiler with the ever so creative name of "tempBF.cpp".

Comment: The OS choice is unimportant in this process.

Comment: You could shell out to a C++ compiler. The alternative would be to write your own C++ toolchain, which is unlikely to be something you would wish to contemplate.

Comment: ***be able to spit out an executable instead of just source code*** Feed the source code into an existing `c++` compiler.

Comment: It's probably easiest to just invoke the command line compiler of your choice

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How would I do this?

Comment: Easiest way would be to generate the appropriate command line to invoke the C++ compiler and then pass the command line to `system`. Providing the scaffolding to auto detect or allow the user to select compilers and set the correct compiler switches will be tricky. Might be worth your time to investigate clang's suite of tools.

Comment: So you're asking how to compile C++ code? Or you're asking how to invoke a C++ compiler from inside a C++ program? More generally, how to run external applications from inside a C++ program? Once you've clearly specified your goal, you'll find that this topic is very well covered already.

Comment: You could avoid the C++ translation and convert Brainfuck directly to an executable.   No need for complex middle steps.  Converting C++ to an executable is a complex step.

Comment: system(g++ tempBF.cpp -o BF.exe); would be probably the fastest solution.

Comment: I know I'm very late here, but can someone explain how to implement the solution @ThomasMatthews proposed?

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se] looking for a `brainfuck` compiler.