# How to use Clang as a library in VC++ projects?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, llvm

I am trying to link LLVM to my C++ project (using Visual Studio 2022), using [Zig's](https://github.com/ziglang/zig) [pre-built binaries](https://ziglang.org/deps/llvm+clang-6.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz).

I have found `libclang.dll` in the `bin` folder however I am unsure how I can link this to my project.

I am hoping to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    LLVMCompileProject(dependencies);
}
```

Before someone suggests this, i am intentionally evoiding using `system` and am trying to directly use LVM.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170

Comment: You cannot compile code from within a project using this.

Comment: I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554592/compile-c-source-code-from-another-c-program) using clang.